# Grub2 has no windows 7 loader in 18.4

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

When I installed 18.4 beside of windows 7 and not functioning 16.4. Grub2 menu there was no Windows but two 16.4.  Here are what I received from boot repair software: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6sJFxVTSDf/. Getting windows back is more important, but two 16.4s are not needed at all.

Comment: You have mixed BIOS/MBR and UEFI installs. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible and once you start booting in one mode, you cannot switch, or grub only boots other installs in same boot mode. You should be able to use Boot-Repair booted in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode and reinstall grub-pc (BIOS version) to MBR. Normally UEFI boot uses gpt partitioned drives, but all your drives are MBR(msdos).

Comment: Try running `sudo update-grub` when you boot 18.04, see if windows 7 boot option is added to the boot selection.

Comment: Unfortunately update-grub did not help.  When 16.04 don't work in my computer the only way seems to be reinstall 18.04 on BIOS mode, if it is possible. Thanks for clearing the problem. mava

Comment: Please don’t put the solution into the question. Use the answer field below instead. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer And please [do not use signature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/217657) under your posts.

Comment: I posted your solution as a community-wiki answer below. Feel free to repost it as your own answer to get the reputation related to it. Then [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) me in a comment to this question, so I can delete the community-wiki answer. If you’ve got another problem (_“The sound is not functioning.”_), please post it as a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with enough HW details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer was originally posted [by the OP as a part of the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1070251/2).*

The solution was reinstalling 18.04, after making changes to BIOS (Legacy) on the computer. All 3rd party drivers are taken within the installation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved the problem

Comment: @user583532 Thanks for your message. If this post could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/217657) the answer using the tick mark (✓).